# Login to SQL Server 2k8 R2 SP1 via Active Directory Group

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, security, windows

I added an Active Directory group as a Windows Authentication Login to our SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

When a user who is a member of that group tries to connect to the server he is given a login failed error.  If I add his specific username as a login, he is then able to connect.

Should I be able to add an Active Directory group to allow users in that group to connect?  It would seem this would be preferred over individually managing specific users.

```
SELECT @@version;

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)
```

Comment: Can you post what kind of error the user received? you might want to take a look at this link and correlate your error with it-    http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx

Comment: Did the user log out and log back in?  Maybe it just needs a refreshing of their security token.

Comment: So I deleted the individual users login and had him re-try and it let him login.  I went to another user that is a member of that group and had him try to login for the first time and it worked.  Moral of the story must be to wait a few moments for the domain controllers to sync up with each other if it's a brand new security group.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that because the security group was literally created moments before I added it as a Windows Auth Login that it hadn't synced yet with all the domain controllers.  It now appears to be functioning properly.

I apologize for the errant question.

Thanks,

Jeremie

Comment: No problem. Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: It's not an errant question - thank you to you for posting the answer, now anyone who is experiencing the same issue can at least know what caused yours. Please go ahead and mark your response as the answer, +1 ;-)